# How to create index for realtionships when using apoc.algo.dijkstra in neo4j

Tags: performance, indexing, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I want to create appropriate indexes on relationships which increase performance when using the apoc.algo.dijkstra algorithm.

My query looks like this
`MATCH (a:Waypoint {name: 'nameTwo'}), (b:Waypoint{name: 'nameOne'}) CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(a, b, 'STREET_A>|STREET_B>', 'distance') yield path as path, weight as distance RETURN path, distance;`

I want indexes for the relationship types 'STREET_A' and 'STREET_B'
I tried to create indexes like these, but it does not seem to make performance difference:
`CREATE INDEX STREET_A_INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR ()-[r:STREET_A]-() ON (r.distance)`

This is the result with PROFILE:
[Plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN6qP.png)

Is it at all possible to make apoc.algo.dijkstra more performant via an index?

[image]

Comment: add keyword PROFILE before MATCH in your query then show us the result. We want to see how the query is using indexes. thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy i have added the result to the post

Comment: The profiled query is using name while your sample query is id. Why is it not in-sync?

Comment: @jose_bacoy I also have indexes on `Waypoint.id` and `Waypoint.name`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a relationship index will help in this case. Indexes are used in Neo4j to find the starting point of a traversal - in your case that would be finding the two `Waypoint` nodes. From the query plan, it looks like you already have an index that is being used to find those nodes.

Neo4j has what's called "index-free adjacency". This means that a traversal from one node to another following a relationship doesn't use an index, rather the operation is more like following pointers - so a relationship index would not be used in your example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation! So there is no other way I can optimize the displayed query?